# ora-03114 not connected to oracle

Tags: errors, oracle-19c

Since the upgrade to the 19C Oracle DB (before 12C) I receive randomly those ORA-03114 error message's.
Before the upgrade I never received it. Any idea's what exactly why those error messages pops up suddenly and what changes needs to be done?

- Domain Win10 PC
- Not all PC's in the domain having this issue
- only localy tnsnames.ora change

ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE

Comment: Did you confirm the initial connection to the database was successful? Was there any error before you started seeing Ora-3114, maybe an ora-3113? If so you should check the database alert log for ORA-7445s which will typically forcibly disconnect sessions for security reasons.

Comment: No its started showing the ORA-03114 immediately. On a different pc its shows the ORA-03113: end-of-file error message at first followed by the ORA-03114

Answer (score 1):

ORA-03114 not connected to ORACLE

Cause: A call to Oracle was attempted when no connection was established. Usually this happens because a user-written program has not logged on. It may also happen if communication trouble causes a disconnection.

Common causes for the ORA-03114 error include:

- Listener process is not running
- DB is shutting down or session has been forcibly disconnected
- Missing entry to the tnsnames.ora
- Network issues such as timeouts
- Problems with connection pooling (shared servers, MTS)

If - as you seem to suggest - your tnsnames.ora was modified recently, an incorrect configuration could be one possible reason for the error, especially if other clients are *not* experiencing any problems. Compare the tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files between the client that fails and the clients that work. Also check the network path for routers or firewalls that could be enforcing idle timeouts, if that is applicable in your environment.

See here for further explanation:

- https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-03114-not-connected-to-oracle/
- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_03114.htm